# In multiple JOIN clauses, can all the ON clauses be moved to the end?

Tags: sql

For example, having tables B and C each one a foreign key to table A, is the following query

```
SELECT A.a, B.b, C.c

FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.PK = B.FK
       INNER JOIN C on A.PK = C.FK
```

equivalent to this one

```
SELECT A.a, B.b, C.c

FROM A INNER JOIN B 
       INNER JOIN C on A.PK = C.FK
                    on A.PK = B.FK
```

?

I have found the second syntax in a query not written by me which I have to understand. 
I've tried the two queries with simple example data and they yield the same recordset, but I need to know if they are equivalent in general or only in particular cases.

And if, instead, table C has a foreign key to table B, which in turn has a foreign key to table A, is the following query

```
SELECT A.a, B.b, C.c

FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.PK = B.FK
       INNER JOIN C on B.PK = C.FK
```

equivalent to

```
SELECT A.a, B.b, C.c

FROM A INNER JOIN B 
       INNER JOIN C on B.PK = C.FK
                    on A.PK = B.FK
```

?

Comment: Are you sure it was exactly like that?  That's certainly not ANSI SQL.  Which RDBMS were you seeing this on?  MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, etc?  Or perhaps it was more like this?  `SELECT * FROM a, b, c WHERE a.PK = b.PK AND a.pk = c.pk`?  That's a legacy notation that has been long replaced by ANSI-92's explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: This is explicit `JOIN` syntax.  `SQL Server` accepts this syntax - they are equivalent, but much harder to follow. Whenever I encounter these, I usually just rewrite them (if I'm able) to the more ANSI-standard way of expressing explicit `JOIN`s.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2014, and the multiple JOIN with some of the ON clauses moved together `( A JOIN B JOIN C ON x=y ON z=w )` came as output of the visual query builder of SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @sagi As far as I'm aware, this syntax works for `OUTER JOIN`s as well.  Personally, I would not advise using this method of moving all of the `ON` clauses to the end, as it makes it hard to follow each `JOIN`.

Comment: I totally agree: reading the JOINs with the ON clauses moved to the end is hard.
In fact my intention was exactly rewriting them with a `( .. JOIN .. ON .. JOIN .. ON .. )` pattern, so I asked this question just to make sure that I am not going to alter the query result in some particular case.